# How can I choose function behavior at compile time?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have 4 files in the following example ; a header, a default implementation file, and 2 platform-specific implementation files.I define two functions; `get_value_1` and `get_value_2`. The 'default' behavior is to return -1, but some of these functions have special implementations. I would like each function to return -1 only if another file didn't implement it.

```
/* interface.h *
***************/
int get_value_1();
int get_value_2();

/* default.c *
*************/
#include "interface.h"

#ifndef GET_VALUE_1
int get_value_1() { return -1; }
#endif

#ifndef GET_VALUE_2
int get_value_2() { return -1; }
#endif

/* platform1.c *
***************/
#include "interface.h"

#ifndef GET_VALUE_1
#define GET_VALUE_1
int get_value_1() { return 1; }
#endif

/* platform2.c *
***************/
#include "interface.h"

#ifndef GET_VALUE_2
#define GET_VALUE_2
int get_value_2() { return 2; }
#endif
```

But when I run the command `gcc default.c platform1.c -shared -fpic -o platform1.so`, it tells me that I've multiply defined the get_value_1 function, and that it was originally defined in platform1.c.

So how can I have a set of functions where a subset of those functions can have their behavior chosen at compile time?

Comment: You could specify only the .c files containing the implementations you want in your Makefile, and leave the .c files of the other implementations out of your program; or alternatively you could use different #ifdef guards around each implementation and pass a -DUSE_GET_VALUE_1 or whatever to the compiler so that only the implementation you want is actually compiled.

Comment: @Jeremy I think I see what you mean with the multiple ifdef guards. That would work but isn't completely ideal. I have many more than just 2 platforms and 2 functions I'm targeting IRL. These platforms also have some pretty irregular overlap with regards to interface requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make them `weak` in the default.c and "normal" in your platform files. So if the platform.c file implements this function as not weak, the weak one dfrom default.c will be replaced link time.

It is not the part of the standard but most compilers support it (it can be pragma, attribute or something else - you need to check in the compiler documentation)

gcc version:

```
#define __weak __attribute__((weak))

/* interface.h *
***************/
int get_value_1();
int get_value_2();

/* default.c *
*************/
#include "interface.h"

#ifndef GET_VALUE_1
__weak  int get_value_1() { return -1; }
#endif

#ifndef GET_VALUE_2
__weak int get_value_2() { return -1; }
#endif

/* platform1.c *
***************/
#include "interface.h"

#ifndef GET_VALUE_1
#define GET_VALUE_1
int get_value_1() { return 1; }
#endif

/* platform2.c *
***************/
#include "interface.h"

#ifndef GET_VALUE_2
#define GET_VALUE_2
int get_value_2() { return 2; }
#endif
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that `weak` is not part of the standard (concerning portability, for example). Anyway,  +1 for describing `weak`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I'll try it now. Did you mean to have a space between your __ and the word weak within default.c?

Comment: The other thing about your suggestion is that I no longer need the #defines. +1 maintainability.

Comment: A propos this __ . When I was learning C in the school I had the teacher I did not like. I wrote my preprocessor to replace everything in my source A-level code with some number of underscores and if the length was longer than 31 I was adding numbers in the random places. All definitions were in the nested include files. and I gave him something like this but much longer longer - several thousands lines :) https://godbolt.org/g/v6jTXt. As a result I was expelled from the school (not only because of it of course :)).